# Changing a list of XTS elements to data frame. How?

Tags: r, dataframe, xts

I'm reading in a bunch of data which is in XTS format,
from a list of tags. After reading them in, I want to convert each one toa data frame in a loop for further
processing. So...I have something like:

## This gets the data

```
    x<-c(<some list of tags>)
    for(i in 1:length(x)) xts<-getXTSData(x[i])
```

Now, I want to process each one, something like:

## Now, the problem...

```
    for(i in 1:length(x))
    {
      df<-<what do I put here>
    }
```

I tried:

```
    df<-as.data.frame(x[i])
    df<-fortify(x[i])
```

Not sure how to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your `xts` object really is of type xts - you can check e.g. using `class(xts) == c("xts", "zoo")` and `inherits(xts, c("zoo", "xts"))` - then `as.data.frame()` should work perfectly fine:

```r
xts <- xts::xts(10.5, order.by = Sys.time())

as.data.frame(xts) 
#>                       V1
#> 2022-08-03 01:16:02 10.5
```

Seems like you should try `as.data.frame(xts)` instead of `as.data.frame(x[i])`.

Comment: Doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: To be fair, there is no specific question asked. You wanted to know how to fix your problem and I told you: Use `as.data.frame(xts)` instead.